# _api/search/suggest?querytext='*' returns empty result

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I'm trying to do a suggestion Query in a SPA. My problem is that all my queries are returning empty results.

I have tried this Query in several different tenants but the rest queries always return empty results. One tenant is used by 3000 users with extensive search all the time so there should be a lot of automatically collected search suggestions.

Do I need to turn something on so SharePoint Online is starting to collect this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions are not available on SPO.

They are not security trimmed and thus could cause information leakage between tenants.

Comment: Thank you! It was not obvious in the documentation.